# Can InstallShield 2011 choose between two versions of a file based on architecture?

Tags: sqlite, installshield-2011

I am trying to build an installer for a web service that can be installed on either x86 or x64 architecture.  As part of our service we are using SQLite3.dll, and the dll is architecture specific.  I need the installer to copy the proper version of the dll based on the architecture of the server.  Is this possible?  If so, how?

Google searches have turned up some complicated ideas concerning mirrored feature/component sets, but I can't help but think there should be an easier way to choose between one source folder location and another based on an architecture flag.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer depends largely on what you're trying to accomplish.

If you just have one overall 32-bit package that happens to deliver one DLL in the platform that matches the machine, you'll need to put each platform variant of it in a different component, and condition those components so that the correct one is installed at run-time. For the basis of your condition, see, for example, the property [Msix64](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370522.aspx).

If you're trying to make two packages, one of which is 32-bit and includes x86 DLLs, and the other is 64-bit and includes x64 DLLs, you should pursue the mirrored components in different features (so you can use [Release Flags](http://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/installshield17helplib/IHelpReleaseFlags.htm) to exclude the set you don't need) and two different product configurations in the releases view. Alternately you can create two mirrored projects.

Note that merely using [Path Variable Overrides](http://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/installshield17helplib/IReleasePathVarOverrides.htm) to select different build sources for the same component is not recommended since your resulting components are for different platforms. This means they should use different component codes, although it's typically only a problem if both installations ever end up on the same machine.

Comment: I tried using the Msix64 (and other properties) approach but not matter what condition I set for the component, the x64 bit file always ends up on the machine.  I have tried leaving condition blank for x86 and using "Msix64>=0" for x64; also tried " Msix64="" " for x86 and "Msix64", "Msix64>=0", "NOT(Msix64="")" for x64 file.  Same result- I always end up with the x64 file.  Also, this service will never have both x64 and x86 versions installed on the same machine so that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: What's the value of Msix64 in the log? Typically I would use the conditions from the list: `Msix64`, `Not Msix64`, or possibly blank as you describe.

Comment: On the 64 bit machine the value is 6; on the 32 bit machine the value is not defined at all.